# Maximum number of paths Map side join can join?

Tags: hadoop

What is the maximum number of paths Map side join can actually join?

I have **n** folders - path/to/folder1 , path/to/folder2 , path/to/folder3 ....so on path/to/foldern in HDFS

path/to/folder1 contains 3 files, say part-1,part-2,part-3.Similarly,each of all the remaining folders have 3 files each with same names as in folder1.

I want to join these folders using map side join like below

pathsToJoin <- path/to/folder1 , path/to/folder2 , path/to/folder3 ....so on path/to/folder**n**

String joinStmt = CompositeInputFormat.compose("outer",TextInputFormat,pathsToJoin);

conf.set("mapred.join.expr", joinStmt);

Since there are 3 files in each folder,the job will spawn 3 map tasks (content of all part-1 files joined to one mapper,content of all part-2 files to 2nd mapper and content of all part-3 files to 3rd mapper) but I would like to know what can be the max value of **n** here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a hard limit in the source code for CompositeInputFormat, the paths are appended to a String expression describing the join and then parsed into splits. You're probably limited by memory, but i imagine you can list 100's if not 1000's without any problem

Comment: Thanks.Looks like there's no limit.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5571 has some details.